# how do i make my input value show up in my application instead of it showing up as an alert?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this the code I have for my GUI I am hoping for help as to how to make the input value display the input as text on screen or even showing how to manipulate it so it looks like a chatroom that i can later integrate a simple chatbot into I mainly just want the texts to show up in the blue section or the "text display" section if someone can please help me. thank you

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");

let win = null;

const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({

    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
};

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white ;
}

input {
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    width: 738px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

button {
    width: 155px;
    height: 42px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

buttonSettings {
    width: 263px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color:white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textDisplay {
    width:930px;
    height: 588px;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

buttonMicrophone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Ali face</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script defer src="render.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="form-group" style="float:right; position: absolute;bottom:0; right:0;">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" placeholder="say anything" id="myInput">
                <buttonMicrophone id="speech" onclick="speechToText()">mic</buttonMicrophone>
                <button id="send" onclick="getInputValue();">Send</button>   
                <script>
                    function getInputValue(){
                        //Selecting the input element and get its value 
                         var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            
                        // Displaying the value
                        <h1>(inputVal);</h1>
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="float:left; position: absolute;top:0; left:0;">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <buttonSettings>Settings</buttonSettings> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="from-group" style="float:right; position: absolute;top:0; right:0;">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <textDisplay></textDisplay>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you couldn't already tell i am also electron for the UI which might help

Answer (score 0):

```
 <textDisplay id="text_area"></textDisplay>
```

then change this function below

```
<script>
                        function getInputValue(){
                            //Selecting the input element and get its value 
                             var inputVal = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
                
                           $('#text_area').text(inputVal)
                        }
                    </script>
```